# dynamic array creation in cython

Tags: performance, numpy, cython

Is there any way to dynamically create arrays in cython without using the horribly ugly kludge of `malloc`+`pointer`+`free`? There has to be *some* refcounting, garbage-collecting wrapper for this very basic function.

I need this to implement a ragged array.

```
inputs=[arr1,arr2,arr3,...]
...
NELEMENTS=len(inputs)
cdef np.ndarray[double,2] lookup[NELEMENTS] #<--- this is where I'm stuck
for i in range(NELEMENTS):
    lookup[i]=inputs[i]

# data.shape =((5000,NELEMENTS))
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    for j in range(data.shape[1]):
        do_something(lookup[j,data[i,j]])
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, there are at least 2 ways of doing what you want:

1) Create a 2-dimensional numpy array, where the size of the 2nd dimension is fixed by the largest of your input arrays. This will waste some space, but is easy, and efficient. You can use the `zeros` function to create a 2-dim array full of zeros, and then just populate the required entries. This is shown below as *Option 1*.

2) Create a nested numpy array, where `lookup2[i]` is a 1-dim numpy array of size defined by the number of elements in `input[i]`. This is also straight-forward, but less efficient, as the internal arrays are stored as generic *Python* objects.

```
inputs = [ [1] ,[2,3,4], [5,6], [7,8,9,10,11,12]]
NELEMENTS=len(inputs)

# Option 1: create 2-dim numpy array full of zeros, and only populate necessary
# parts
maxInputSize = max( [len(x) for x in inputs] )

cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=2] lookup = np.zeros( (NELEMENTS, maxInputSize) )

for i in range(NELEMENTS):
    for j in range(len(inputs[i])):
        lookup[i][j] = inputs[i][j]

# Option 2: create nested numpy array
cdef np.ndarray[object, ndim=1] lookup2 = np.empty( (NELEMENTS,), dtype='object' )

for i in range(NELEMENTS):

    nInputs = len(inputs[i])
    lookup2[i] = np.zeros(nInputs)

    for j in range(nInputs):
        lookup2[i][j] = inputs[i][j]
```